# When should I use 经验 and when should I use 经历?

Tags: grammar

Can I say "跟据我的经历那儿的人很友好"? Is this a correct sentence?

Should I use 经历, 经验, or is there a better way to say this sentence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a Chinese, I think “经历” would be a better choice.

- “经验”

“经验” often refers to some knowledge or work experience，for example，“I am expert in programming and algorithms”，then  I can say “根据我的经验，我可以给你一些编程技巧”.

- “经历”

“经历” refers to some personal experience during life，study，work，travel and so on. For example，“I have a good travel to China”，then I can say，“我曾经在中国有一个美好的经历，根据我经历的事情（或者根据我的经历），我认为大多数中国人都比较腼腆而友好”.

Answer (score 3):

“经历” and “经验” are both similar word of experience in English but put emphasis on different aspect.

For “经历”, it puts emphasis on the personal experience that someone had.

For “经验”, it puts emphasis on the skills or knowledge that someone had summarized from a series of events.

On this basis, both “经历” and “经验” are okay in terms of meaning in your sentence. The best choice out of them depends on your emphasis as described above.

Answer (score 2):

According to my dictionary (source 1: 辭海  趙錫如 主編 將門文物 出版):

經歷:
1) 履歷
2)曾做過或看過某件事

經驗: 
1) 親身做過或見過
...which is as clear as mud! So let's break it down some more:

歷:
動詞:經驗、經過、曾經；例:歷久。
形詞:以往的，過去的；例:歷朝。
名詞:與[曆]字通。
From this, we see that its meaning encompasses "experienced", "past", and was interchangeable with "calendar".

驗:
名詞:證明；例:何以為驗。
形詞:有效的；例:驗方。
動詞:測試；例:試驗。
動詞:檢查；例:查驗。
From this, we see that there's a "test with attention to results" component, like trial and error.

Thus, we can see that 經歷 is more appropriately used to describe an experience you had, noun form. Think 歷史, history. You were there at a point in time. Contrast this with 經驗, which is akin to insights you gleamed from being somewhere at some point in time.

In my google search, this [post](http://www.synnex.com.tw/asp/emba/synnex_short_content.aspx?infovalue=56&seqno=22213) captured it best, especially with its title "有經歷，不等於有經驗".

Edit: sorry, it has occurred to me I did not answer the question.

In common speech, "經驗" would be the more appropriate term to use in the situation you've described. You are sharing an insight derived from a past event in your life.

[Update 4/6/2016; found an online source with examples supporting my writing above]
From http://yun.dreye.com/dict_new/dict.php :

> 經驗:
>   (a) experience; a lesson
>   Examples:
>   他以巨大代價獲得這方面經驗。He paid dearly for his experience.
>   缺乏實際經驗的空頭理論家 an armchair theorist deficient in practical experience
>   以上來源於：《漢英大辭典》

Compare this with 經歷

> 1) to go through; to undergo; to experience; to come through; to undergo an experience
>   2) one's past experience; a professional career; adventure
>   Examples:
>   孩子們被那個水手的冒險經歷迷住了。
>   The boys were charmed by the sailor's adventure.
>   請跟我們談談你在非洲的經歷。
>   Please tell us about your experiences in Africa.
>   以上來源於：《漢英大辭典》

Comment: Based on the definitions, I think there isn't a correct answer for this because it depends on what the person wants to say exactly. It is like translating the sentence into "According to my experience, the people over there are very friendly." versus. "According to what I know, the people over there are very friendly." Both are correct semantically, but the correct word depends on what the person asking the question wants to say/emphasize.

Comment: I'm quite surprised my paper dictionary provided the answer it did. Respectfully, I disagree with what you're saying. What you know and what you experience is two concepts; what you know doesn't need to be based on your experience. I had some time to search online, will post my findings shortly.

Comment: sorry, can't see how to edit comments. I meant to say, what you know and what you experience are two separate concepts.

Answer (score 0):

looking up both words in e.g. iciba, in particular considering the example sentences would suggest the
answer, namely 经验, for more examples see jukuu, in fact feed "according to my experience" to jukuu and find
1. 1.   I would offer some tips according to my own experience.
    根据我的经验，我可以提供一些小建议。

Answer (score 0):

I think 经验 is a little bit more better in your sentence. 经历 sounds more serious and longer, like this sentence

> a miserable experience(经历) in war time
>
> 一段战争年代的痛苦**经历**