# What is the difference between 经验 and 经历?

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference between these two words - 经历 and 经验? Both mean `experience` in English.

If there is a difference, how can I use it accordingly?

Comment: see previous Q https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17631/when-should-i-use-%e7%bb%8f%e9%aa%8c-and-when-should-i-use-%e7%bb%8f%e5%8e%86

Comment: web search using e.g. 经验和经历有什么区别 leads to more results, e.g. https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/2140454214852743828.html

Comment: Ah, that sounds a duplicate. Sorry for overlooking it. I closed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way to differentiate these two phrases. "经历" is something you have experienced in the past, whereas "经验" is conclusions, BKMs (best known method) or any useful knowledge you had gotten from those experiences (those 经历s).

Answer (score 2):

经历 stresses on the passive side, while 经验 on the active side. Like in a fire, it is not your intention to have such an experience because it is a disaster, but you get through it, so that is 经历， but when you tell others what you feel about or what you have learnt from it, that is 经验. That is my understanding, and hope it is helpful.